# Laravel & MongoDB and an advanced role/permission system

Tags: mongodb, permissions, laravel-5, user-permissions, user-roles

I know there are a lot of role/permission packages like [bican/roles](https://github.com/romanbican/roles) or [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) .

They are great but I have two problems and those packages can't solve it!

1. I am using mongoDB and [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) package which those packages do not support mongo.
2. And I need a multi-level/item-based role-permission system. I mean, for example: a user can edit just post 2 and post 3. NOT all posts!

So, I decided to develop that system myself, before starting it, I want your expertise to give me advice, useful links, articles, other packages, and anything which may help me.

Comment: This question is too broad and will result in opinionated answers. Please try to ask questions around specific code issues.

Answer (score 4):

you could use that it is almost like spatie/laravel-permission but for mongo db https://github.com/mostafamaklad/laravel-permission-mongodb

You just could create a permission with that post and give it to the user

or give it to a role and assign the role to the user